# Comparing many timestamps with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes with different sizes containing timestamps. I need to find nearest timestamps. In df A I need to find all first timestamps after any of timestamps of df B. The dataframes have each around 100,000 rows so iteration is not a way and even `df.apply()` took around 6 mins.

e.g.:

```
A:
11
12
15
16
18
20
25
30
50

B:
14
19
22
27

result:
15
20
25
30
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.searchsorted`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.searchsorted.html):

```
out = a.loc[a['A'].searchsorted(b['B']), 'A']
print (out)
2    15
5    20
6    25
7    30
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Great, clean and fast! Thanks :)